# Removing Legendary Skill Ranks in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I'm running `SkyRE`, and one of the known bugs is that the Longbow's `Overdraw` perk will break occasionally when adding a new perk to the Longbow tree.

The fix is to Legendary the `Marksman` skill, then use `player.setav <skillName> <skillLvl>` to reset the skill to it's previous level. Then re-add all the perks.

This works fine, and seems to be the only fix available. However, it's left me with several legendary skill ranks that I haven't earned. I've looked around for a console command to erase Legendary levels to no avail.

Anyone else have a solution to reset the Legendary count to 0?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try crafting new alchemy armor?

Comment: Just note that legendary ranks actually do nothing afaik, other than having a number there...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this in the console, but SKSE does expose a scripting API for adding and removing legendary levels, if you're willing to get your hands dirty writing your own mod.  You could do something like the following in a Papyrus script:

```
ActorValueInfo.GetActorValueInfo("Marksman").SetSkillLegendaryLevel(0)
```

(This cannot be typed at the console; it has to be compiled into a Papyrus script and then executed by the game's scripting engine.  Also, it requires a reasonably recent version of SKSE - if for some strange reason you must use an older version, use the deprecated [`Game.SetSkillLegendaryLevel()`](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=SetSkillLegendaryLevel_-_Game) instead.)